# How to get process ID of browser child process after BrowserChildProcessHostImpl->Launch

Tags: c++, chromium

In the context of the Chromium open source code,
I'm developing a class which extends from `content::BrowserChildProcessHostDelegate` and `IPC::Sender`. Inside one of the methods of my class I launch a child process like so:

```
scoped_ptr<BrowserChildProcessHostImpl> process_;
...
process_->Launch(
#if defined(OS_WIN)
     new MySandboxedProcessLauncherDelegate,
#elif defined(OS_POSIX)
     false, // don't use zygote
     env,
#endif
     cmd_line);
```

**Question:** How can one get the PID of the child process which is being created by this `Launch` function?

**EDIT:** Simply calling the following function right after `Launch` does not work:

```
base::ProcessHandle child_handle = process_->GetHandle();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling `process_->GetHandle();` inside my class, in the overridden method: `virtual void OnProcessLaunched() OVERRIDE;` as shown in the code below:

```
void MyProcessHost::OnProcessLaunched() {
      MyProcessHost::child_process_handle_ = this->process_->GetHandle();
}
```

I used a static field: `static base::ProcessHandle child_process_handle_` to store the value of the handle, but you can of course, use a non-static field as well.